# Need help decompiling .img file on Ubuntu to theme UI

Tags: themes, disk-image

Sorry if it's been asked before but I have this aftermarket digital cluster in my jeep and it runs some kind of Linux version in it. I was wondering if I could get some help in decompiling the `update.img` on Ubuntu so I can change the color of the jeep on there (see image below). I'm a complete noob with Ubuntu and Linux but I'm really hoping someone can help me out.

[image: image of UI]

I'm running Ubuntu on VirtualBox. I was hoping I could decompile it on that Ubuntu system, to make the changes I need then recompile it.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjT3Yr76N_lAhWKb30KHQ4VDywQjRx6BAgBEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpikdo.net%2Fp%2Fcarobotor%2F2112760189884553998_10352179187&psig=AOvVaw1NUiAGjpumblfTOppJ3T-a&ust=1573481339573105

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes I'm running Ubuntu on virtual box. I was hoping I could decompile it on Ubuntu to make the changes I need then recompile it.